# how to scroll text and background images separately one at a time

Tags: html, css, parallax

I tried to describe in the text of the question what I want to do.  I'm not at all sure it's clear.  hopefully the code will help clarify..

```css
html { 
  background: url(paradise_duplicate.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
            
        .first_background{
              background: url(paradise_duplicate.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;

            }
        .second_background{
              background: url(strumpf_village_2.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;

            }
        .box{
            display: inline-block; /* Make the width of box same as image */
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 999;
            margin: 0 auto;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0; /* Adjust this value to move the positioned div up and down */
            text-align: center;
            width: 90%; /* Set the width of the positioned div */
             }
        div.transbox {
            margin: 30px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: 1px solid black;
            opacity: 0.6;
            }
        div.transbox p {
            margin: 2.5%;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000000;
            }
        div.no_transbox {
            margin: 30px;
            }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home3_simple.css" />
    <style>
    </style>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <div class = "first_background">
        <div class="box">
                <div class="transbox">
                    <p>first text
                    <br><br>
                    text
                    </p>
                </div>
                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                <div class="transbox">
                    <p>
                    more text
                    </p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "second_background">
        <div class="box">
                <div class="transbox">
                    <p>
                    more and more text
                    </p>
                </div>
                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                <div class="transbox">
                    <p>
                    last text
                    </p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

In more detail, what I want to do is put up a first image, have the text scroll while it stays in place, then, as the last of the text associated with the first image comes onto the screen, the background image starts moving with it, so that a second background image comes onto the screen.  once this new background image is fully on the screen, the text associated with -it- now scrolls accross the screen with the background image fixed.  and this continues for as many background images/text as necessary.. my code manifestly does not work.  the background comes from the html tag, the div tags do nothing..  and yes.. I make no claim that the code as written is in any way professional, or will even work cross-platform.. at best, it can serve as an example of what I want to do for other professionals later on to re-write..

Edit:  while is it's exactly what I described above, the following is likely what is actually possible to do only with css, and the thing that inspired me:  https://www.codesdope.com/blog/article/fixed-background-scrolling-effect-using-css/

Comment: `css` and `html` unable to solve, you need to use `javascript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@juggler

Please try this code,To scroll text and background images separately one at a time

```
   <div id="frame">
    <article>  
    <div class="parallax">
        <div class="bg__foo">foo</div>
        <div class="bg__bar">bar</div>
        <div class="bg__baz">baz</div>
        <div class="bg__bazz">bazz</div>
      </div>
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Example for 'background-attachment : fixed'</h1>
      </div>
      <section>
        <div class="container">
          <p>No speeches. Short speech. You lost your partner today. What's his name - Emilio? Emilio is going to prison. The DEA took all your money, your lab. You got nothing. Square one. But you know the business and I know the chemistry. I'm thinking... maybe you and I could partner up. </p>
          <p>I'm sorry, what were you asking me? Oh, yes, that stupid plastic container I asked you to buy. You see, hydrofluoric acid won't eat through plastic. It will, however, dissolve metal, rock, glass, ceramic. So there's that. How about something with some protein, maybe? Something green, huh? How are you even alive? </p>
          <p>That is seventeen five - your half of the thirty-five thousand. Plus there's an extra fifteen in there, it's all yours, you've earned it. We made a deal. That's right. Because I think that we can do business together - we came to an understanding. Take a look at the money in your hand. Now just imagine making that every week. That's right. Two pounds a week, thirty-five thousand a pound. </p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="parallax">
        <div class="bg__break">
          <div class="capture">I... am very sorry. Is there anything I can do? I am on the board of this hospital. I can recommend doctors. Make sure he gets whatever he needs. The best treatment. How did that happen?</div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div class="container">
          <p>What kind of man talks to the DEA? No man. No man at all. A crippled little rata. What a reputation to leave behind. Is that how you want to be remembered? Last chance to look at me, Hector. Can I help you sir? What can I do for you? I'm... sorry, I'm not following. I... think that you're confusing me for someone else. Sir, if you have a complaint, I suggest you submit it through our email system. I will be happy to refer you to our website. </p>
          <p>I don't think we're alike at all, Mr. White. You are not a cautious man at all. Your partner was late and he was high. He's high often, isn't he? You have poor judgement. I can't work with someone with poor judgement. I've been told, it's excellent. That is not the only factor. I have to ask... why? Why him? How much product do you have on hand? I have your numbers. You can never trust a drug addict. </p>
          <p>I didn't say I killed him. Dude's wife crushed his head with an ATM machine. Crushed his head... with an ATM machine... right in front of me. I mean, crushed it like... Oh my god, the sound... it's still in my ears. You know and the the blood, like everywhere. Like there was so much you would not believe. Man will you just please give me... just give me my weed alright? It helps with my nausea. </p>
          <p>Four pounds... foooour pounds as if two pounds wasn't bad enough. we're talking two three hundred boxes of sinus pills there ain't that many Smurfs in the world. So no sudo? So you do have a plan! Yeah, Mr. White! Yeah, science!   Yo... it's appointment only! Jeez, you look like... Lex Luthor. I got two dudes turned into raspberry slushy and flushed down my toilet. I can't even take a proper dump in there. I mean the whole damn house has gotta be haunted by now. </p>
          <p>You didn't actually see Tuco? You got this money from Tuco? Tuco gave you this is what you're saying? You made a deal? How... why would you make a deal with that scumbag? You see what he did to me? No way man, okay, no understanding! Without even talking to me, you told this... insane ass-clown, dead-eyed killer, that uh... that we would give him two pounds a week? </p>
          <p>Don't talk to me about hours, what about sudo, man? How are we gonna get that? You think the meth fairy is gonna just bring it to us? God it takes me a week to get this stuff. I'm driving all the way up to Las Cruces, two hundred miles each way to meet up with my Smurfs. The dudes who go to the drug stores and get a couple boxes at a time and then sell 'em to me. And that's maybe only good for, like a half pound worth. See that's the bottle neck in your brilliant business plan. Of course you would've known that if you would've just asked me. </p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
    </div>
    html, body {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      color: rgb(235,235,235);
    background-color:rgb(20,20,20);
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:4px;
    }
   .demo-frame header {
        display: none;
    }
   .demo-wrapper {
        min-height: 500px;
    }
    .bsap_1280449 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    .parallax [class*="bg__"] {
      position: relative;
      height: 300px;
      text-indent: -9999px;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: top center;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    .parallax [class*="bg__"]:nth-child(2n) {
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 1em #111;
    }
    .parallax .bg__foo, .parallax .bg__bazz {
      height: 100vh;
    }
    .parallax .bg__foo {
      background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/30354/parallax1.jpg);
    }
    .parallax .bg__bar {
      background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/30354/parallax2.jpg);
    }
    .parallax .bg__baz {
      background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/30354/parallax3.jpg);
    }
    .parallax .bg__bazz {
      background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/30354/parallax1.jpg);
    }
    .parallax .bg__break {
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 1em #111;
      background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/30354/parallax1.jpg);
    }
    .parallax .capture {
      float: right;
      width: 200px;
      padding: 1em;
      margin: -1.5em 1em 0 0;
      text-indent: 0;
      background: rgba(243, 243, 243, 0.75);
      box-shadow: 0 1px 0.125em #333;
      color:rgb(20,20,20);
    }
article .container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
article .header {
  position: relative;
  margin: -5em 0 0 0;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #333;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
article h1, article h2 {
  margin: 0 0 0.333em;
}
article section {
  padding: 3em;
}
article section.parallax {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#frame {
  width:960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.

Thank you.

Comment: thank you for the example of code.  still working out exactly what it does and how.  that said, the only places where there is not the original background picture that has things moving on it is where the background is just black, and it isn't obvious that if one were to continue scrolling, that the text would also continue scrolling..

Comment: Only just re-stumbled on this question.  I now have a website that works quite nicely (as of a long time ago), so, in the spirit of being friendly, I'm going to accept it, assuming that it did indeed help :-)